# How to kill a process programatically using c++?

Tags: c++, linux, signals, posix

Guys i am trying to kill the process through the C++ program , it's killing the process,  but  not getting the desired output after killing the process, my desired output is to display the remaining running processes after killing the process which is in if block ,instead of that it is displaying the else block. I inter changed if block & else block too still not getting the desired output. 
Here  is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<csignal>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int pid,f=0;
    system("ps -all");
    cout<<"Enter the Process ID to kill\n";
    cin>>pid;
    if((kill(pid,SIGKILL))){
        f=1;
    }
    if(f)
    {
        cout<<"List of processes after killing the process with PID"<<pid<<"are"<<"\n";
        system("ps -l");
    }
    else    
    {   
        cout<<"Cant kill the process\n";
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am working on ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Always a good idea to read the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) of the functions you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch your if/else cases:  `kill()` returns 0 when it succeeds, and -1 when it fails.  You're setting `f=1` only when it fails.

Also, when it fails, it sets `errno` to an error code that provides a reason for the failure.  You can use a function like `perror()` or `strerror()` to get a descriptive error message based on that error code.

Comment: I interchanged if/else cases but not getting.

Comment: Do you mean that it's still printing the "can't kill the process" message even after you moved that code to the `if` block?

Comment: @Venki, you are doing something else wrong.  This is the correct answer.  You don't even need variable F.

Comment: Then I can't help you further, because your code works correctly for me (with the if/else blocks swapped).